# Navigating to specific URL only IF specified ID withing that URL exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

So I have this HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Background</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn" target="_blank" >CLICK ME</button>
</body>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

and this JS code

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {

    var test=makeid();
    window.open("http://www."+test,'_blank');
};

function makeid()
{
var url = "";
var possible = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
    url += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

return url;
}
```

How to make client jump to this randomly generated URL only if a div(on the page with generated URL) with id="hehe" exists?If it doesn't exist generate URL again.Is it done using AJAX or something else?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Since as described and written, you're going to be opening alot of extra windows (and hence annoy the user) before finding a correct one. Or are you going to reroute a couple thousand variations of the random url to the same page?

Comment: I dont want to open a lot of pages, I only want to open 1.I want to be generating random URLS until I find the page with that ID.Is it possible to do so without opening all of the pages?I want to do it in the background or something like that.Hope i explained a little bit better

Comment: Explain better WHY you need to open a page with a random URL. It is possible what you're trying to do, but the way you're trying to create it, will give you issues. So I'm trying to understand what you're doing first. So explain what these pages are, why they need to have a random URL and why you want to check them all every time instead of just checking a database or the server containing these pages. Will you actually Have all those pages? Or will you get alot of 404, page not found errors? I understand What you're trying to do, but not Why. :)

Comment: It's just a personal project.Just trying to learn something new :).Ok,so if you say I can check the server,is it possible to check facebook servers for containing some pages?If I create random URL for a facebook page and only access if it contains an image with specific ID?However, I doubt you can access facebook servers to check if a page exists, so you have to do it some other way.

Comment: You can't check facebook pages this way no. I'm just being difficult about it because it's terrible design. Suppose you use ajax to fetch all of these sites. If it exists, you then have to parse it. All the other pages will return a 404. Since some browsers will only allow 4 pages to be ajaxed at the same time, it could take hours before the script finishes. If you want to use it with fb, look at the facebook API to help you instead of writing a web crawler that tests random urls.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript  And preferably, do this on a server.

Comment: Sorry for asking not so smart questions(started learning Ajax few days ago).Is there a way around this?Create random URL, ajax that page, if ID exists redirect user that page,if it doesn't,create random URL and so on.I just want it somehow to check for ID ONLY in the background before it redirects the user.

Comment: Try to think of a way that you don't need random urls, since that is what will cause you issues, the sheer amount of nonexisting pages you'll try to look at. For example: using the fabecook SDK to try logging in as that user without sending a password. This will tell you if the user exists or not. It's a slight improvement over random urls. Anyways, just try your own solution either with ajax or with `window.open(url);` and you'll quickly notice where the issues are.